# Zip files containing only spaces and no extension

Tags: zip

I have been using to zip up some icon files.

But for a project I needed to rename some .png files to filenames using only spaces and no extension.

```
zip -u icons.zip *.*
```

But now it does not zip those files?

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

- Matches any number of characters. You can use the asterisk (*) anywhere in a character string.

  zip -u icons.zip *